# My cURL became broken, I think login page is redirecting to alternate URL

Tags: php, redirect, curl, authentication

I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas here. This is a method for getting a basic HTML table on a webpage of organizations, 30 at a time, paginated with HTML links to increment the 'orgs' variable that allows you to move on to the next 30 by changing the URL.

```
$number = 1;
$zenLink = "https://z2.zendesk.com/organizations.xml?page=".$number;


if (isset($_GET['orgs'])){ 
$number = $_GET['orgs'];
$number = $number + 1;
$zenLink = "https://z2.zendesk.com/organizations.xml?page=".$number;
}

//Above is the incrementer for next page navigation links to get paginated Zendesk list of orgs

$c = curl_init($zenLink);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user@email.com:password'); //ZENDESK login

$page = curl_exec($c);
echo $page;
```

$page spits out "Couldn't authenticate you." It might be some curl option I need to set, I just don't know what it is. I have a feeling it is the curl options for following redirects, but I don't know how I'd source it given my source code above... this exact code was working like a week ago...before the login URL redirect was put in place.

Comment: Maybe, you just provide wrong login/password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first step in debugging cURL is always to turn on VERBOSE and write it to a log.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$fh = fopen('curl.log', 'w');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fh);
```

Now executing the cURL handler will output debugging information to curl.log, which will hopefully say something useful. If Harry is correct and you need to turn off SSL_VERIFYHOST then the log will say something about "host could not be verified".

Comment: Hi, thanks for this cool method. The log reported back:              < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: nginx/1.0.15
< Date: Wed, 18 Apr 2012 21:41:51 GMT
< Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
< Connection: keep-alive
< Status: 401 Unauthorized
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.

Comment: Are you setting CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH (most likely to CURLAUTH_BASIC) and CURLOPT_USERPWD to "[username]:[password]" where username and password are login info for htaccess? If you are, are the username and password correct? This page has more information [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: Thanks for these great suggestions - the cause was actually the website I was pulling from denying authentication via username and password, which was a setting I had to turn on - however, these suggestions were great, I know how to troubleshoot in the future - thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can set an option to stop it from verifying, you can try this.

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

If that doesn't work then you will want to check your username and password